# Dynamically export a module by reading all files in a directory in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

So today i was trying read all **default exports**
 from some directory which has **index.js**. Try to wrap it inside one object and export it back again. Is there a better way to handle this ?

```
 export default (() => require('fs')
            .readdirSync(__dirname)
            .filter(fileName => !!/.js$/ig.test(fileName))
            .map(fileName => fileName.split('.')[0])
            .reduce((defaultExportObj, nextFileName) => {
                try {
                    return {
                        ...defaultExportObj,
                        [nextFileName]: require(__dirname + `/${nextFileName}`),
                    };
                }catch(err) { throw err; }
            }, {}))();
```

Comment: There is hopefully some Webpack plugin to do this.

Comment: You might be looking for https://github.com/gajus/create-index or https://github.com/ryardley/indexr

Answer (score 2):

I guess i'd do something like this - not sure if this is better - w/e better is ^^

> webpack: [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext)

```
function expDefault(path, mode = "sync"){

    const modules = {}
    const context = require.context(path, false, /\.js$/, mode)
    context.keys().forEach(file => {
        const name = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.js$/, "$1")
        modules[name] = context(name).default
    })
    return modules
}
export default expDefault(__dirname)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Estradiaz. Will definitely give it a try.